# Jsoup: getting table with space in class name

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm new with Jsoup and not very expert with HTML. I'm trying to get some data from a table in a website.

If I inspect element (from Chrome) on the table I need, I get:

```
<table class=" table-main" id="tournamentTable!>
<colgroup>...</colgroup>
<tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

When I run the command

```
Elements e = doc.select("table.table-main");
```

and then printed the content of `e`, I noted that it takes another table of the page whose class is `<table class="table-main top-event">`.

Since in class name `class=" table-main"` there is a withespace, I made other attempts, like `doc.select("table[class= table-main]");` but this returned me a 0-sized element.

I tried to give a look at HTML code and I noted that there is no table with class name " table-main". Could be this the reason?

Comment: Space shouldn't be considered as part of class name. `Elements e = doc.select("table.table-main")` should return *all* tables which have class `table-main`, but that doesn't exclude case where table has also other classes like `<table class="table-main top-event">`. If you want to pick table with only your class try `doc.select("table[class=table-main]");` (without space)

Comment: Have you inspected the source in chrome with disabled JavaScript? Always keep in mind that jsoup has no JavaScript support. State the actual url, otherwise we are just guessing around.

Comment: @Pshemo: It's one of the attempts I made before posting but it's not working

Comment: @FredericKlein I've just checked the problem is JavaScript. Disabling it, I cannot see the table I'm interested in. So, if Jsoup has no JavaScript support, can you suggest me an other library that support JavaScript? 

If it could be useful, this is the link http://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/argentina/atp-buenos-aires/results/

Thanks

Comment: For a Java-only approach have a look at HtmlUnit. The documentation section has a tutorial for using HtmlUnit in combination with jsoup: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/4632/parsing-javascript-generated-pages#t=201610180720238960961 If other tools/languages aren't a problem, I would give phantomJS a try to fetch the rendered html source, then parse the file with jsoup.

Comment: @FredericKlein Thanks a lot. I will have a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it looks as though the HTML is invalid `id="tournamentTable!` instead of `id="tournamentTable"`.  This could cause the JSOUP parser some difficulties.

Secondly, if you are attempting to select the tournament table cited in your example then I would recommend selecting by id rather than css class: `doc.select("#tournamentTable")`.